# Swift Sprite-kit SKPhyshicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a few images that can detect when they get touched right now I am using

```
plane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: plane.frame.height / 2)
```

but I need it so it is the boarder of the image not a circle or rectangle.

Comment: What do you want it to be?

Comment: i want it to fix the size of the image assigned to it, it is a complex 2d object that a circle and rect does not fit its exact size. So i need to make the physicsbody fit the exact size of the image @Knight0fDragon

Comment: then use SKPhysicsBody(texture:),  if your sprite consists of multiple nodes, create a texture out of it by view.textureFromNode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Put that as a formal answer. That's definitely the correct answer as long as his picture uses clear pixels

Comment: nah the question should just be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a plane and you want a physical body. 
Your first approach is **circleOfRadius** (the physical representation is a circle with a given radius). You can use another shape, such a **rectangle**:

```
plane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(100, height: 100))
```

As explained in the comments you can also use the shape of a sprite (texture) to create the shape of the physics body:

```
plane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texure: plane.texture!, size: plane.size)
```

But a good way to choose it's this: if you want your game to run smootly on many different devices, don't make sure the physics calculations become  too complicated. In other words if you have many object around your plane with physical behavior moving around  and colliding with each other, you may choose to use simplified shapes to deal with the physics more efficiently, especially if a shape already looks a lot like a rectangle or a circle.

Comment: ok So i've used that line of code before with the texture, but if it touches anything my texture starts to spin, is there a way to set the plane stationary when collision so it doesn't spin it just stays in the same way when started? @Alessandro Ornano

Comment: You could enable skView.showPhysics = true to see if these sizes are correct about physicsBodies..